# Unity move images from 0 to 1920 infinitely for a parallax effect

Tags: unity-game-engine, parallax

I have 5 different images from this [asset pack](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/2d/environments/pixel-cave-parallax-bg-76551?fbclid=IwAR2fEvAAgqynlTvBiEQKEhW8BPFt-6Vd9N7HECbGZ3GH4dyzadLP4jvZebc).

I want to use them as a background in my start screen. I just want them to move (parallax style) infinitely.

They are images not sprites, so they are rendered on a canvas element.

I now have trouble understanding how to move them from 0 to 1920, so they dont leave the camera. I could move them, but they will move out of camera.

Here is an example how I move one layer with a coroutine:

```
public IEnumerator PlayParallax() {
        while (true) {
            imageContainer.GetComponentInChildren<Image>().transform.position = new Vector3(imageContainer.GetComponentInChildren<Image>().transform.position.x + 1, imageContainer.GetComponentInChildren<Image>().transform.position.y, imageContainer.GetComponentInChildren<Image>().transform.position.z);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: `imageContainer.GetComponentInChildren<Image>().transform.position` is equivalent to `imageContainer.transform.position` and possibly just `imageContainer.position`. Additionally, you can do `imageContainer.position += new Vector3(1,0,0);`. Now, your problem. Of course the images are leaving the camera, the images need to be larger than the screen to start with and positioned far enough *left* that it leaves the screen on that side before you start moving it.

Comment: @Draco18s no, not if the `Image` component is placed on a child object of `imageContainer` instead of the `imageContainer` itself... And it doesn't look like `imageContainer` is of type `Tranform` or `RectTransform` .. this sounds like speculations .. ;)

Comment: Did you try asking the creator of that Asset how it works? I would expect that this is the best source for information. I have very little ambition to have to buy an Asset in order to answer a question about it ;)

Comment: @derHugo Fair enough, but calling GetComponent a bunch of times is not good. Store it in a local variable if it is absolutely needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, by making a copy of each layer. For example layer_0 is visible in camera view, layer_0_0 is to the left. Both move and when layer_0 completely left the camera it is placed at the beginning and so on:

```
public class ParalaxPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] GameObject imageContainer;

    public IEnumerator PlayParallax() {
        while (true) {
            // first layer
            imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[0].transform.position = new Vector3(imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[0].transform.position.x + 0.3f, 
                imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[0].transform.position.y, imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[0].transform.position.z);
            imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[1].transform.position = new Vector3(imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[1].transform.position.x + 0.3f, 
                imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[1].transform.position.y, imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[1].transform.position.z);

            if (imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[0].transform.position.x >= 1920) {
                imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[0].transform.position = new Vector3(-1920, 0, 0);
            }

            if (imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[1].transform.position.x >= 1920) {
                imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[1].transform.position = new Vector3(-1920, 0, 0);
            }

            // seconds layer
            imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[2].transform.position = new Vector3(imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[2].transform.position.x + 0.7f,
                imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[2].transform.position.y, imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[2].transform.position.z);
            imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[3].transform.position = new Vector3(imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[3].transform.position.x + 0.7f, 
                imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[3].transform.position.y, imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[3].transform.position.z);

            if (imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[2].transform.position.x >= 1920) {
                imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[2].transform.position = new Vector3(-1920, 0, 0);
            }

            if (imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[3].transform.position.x >= 1920) {
                imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[3].transform.position = new Vector3(-1920, 0, 0);
            }

            // third layer
            imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[4].transform.position = new Vector3(imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[4].transform.position.x + 1.1f,
                imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[4].transform.position.y, imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[4].transform.position.z);
            imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[5].transform.position = new Vector3(imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[5].transform.position.x + 1.1f,
                imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[5].transform.position.y, imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[5].transform.position.z);

            if (imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[4].transform.position.x >= 1920) {
                imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[4].transform.position = new Vector3(-1920, 0, 0);
            }

            if (imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[5].transform.position.x >= 1920) {
                imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[5].transform.position = new Vector3(-1920, 0, 0);
            }

            // fourth layer
            imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[6].transform.position = new Vector3(imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[6].transform.position.x + 1.5f,
                imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[6].transform.position.y, imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[6].transform.position.z);
            imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[7].transform.position = new Vector3(imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[7].transform.position.x + 1.5f,
                imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[7].transform.position.y, imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[7].transform.position.z);

            if (imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[6].transform.position.x >= 1920) {
                imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[6].transform.position = new Vector3(-1920, 0, 0);
            }

            if (imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[7].transform.position.x >= 1920) {
                imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[7].transform.position = new Vector3(-1920, 0, 0);
            }

            // fifth layer
            imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[8].transform.position = new Vector3(imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[8].transform.position.x + 1.9f,
                imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[8].transform.position.y, imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[8].transform.position.z);
            imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[9].transform.position = new Vector3(imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[9].transform.position.x + 1.9f,
                imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[9].transform.position.y, imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[9].transform.position.z);

            if (imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[8].transform.position.x >= 1920) {
                imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[8].transform.position = new Vector3(-1920, 0, 0);
            }

            if (imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[9].transform.position.x >= 1920) {
                imageContainer.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>()[9].transform.position = new Vector3(-1920, 0, 0);
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.005f);
        }   
    }

    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(PlayParallax());
    }

    void Update() {

    }
}
```